# What are some ideal ways to add update feature to a python project?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, command-line-interface

I am working on a python project that I have hosted on github. I plan to release an initial version to the community. The problem is this: I want people to be able to update it newer versions as and when available by running some command like this:

```
cf-cli.py update
```

What are some of the most native ways to this? --that which does not require any additional installation other than python itself.

Comment: Your users are likely to have `pip` installed. Just use that, it's the defacto standard.

Answer (score 2):

Add it to PyPI - the Python Package Index.

The Python Package Index is a repository of software for the Python programming language.

Your users can install it and upgrade it as new versions come out as and when they want to without any issues.

You will have to do some basic work like creating a .pypirc file and make accounts on [PyPI Live](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=register_form%20PyPI) and [PyPI Test](https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=register_form).

You'll also have to make a `setup.py` and `setup.cfg` and of course a `LICENSE.txt`.

After all this you'll have to upload them to PyPI and you're done.

Here's an in depth [tutorial](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html) that covers the steps in much greater detail.